# To check varchar values and avoid duplicate entries in MySQL table

Tags: mysql-python, mysql

I need to run a application to collect the news feeds and update new entries in my database. So I planned to create two tables one source and other as target.
My plan is to first update all the information into source table and latter update target table with unique data (currently updated news or new records).

But the issue is some feeds are repeated in some other websites. so the application breaks immediately after reading a duplicate entry.

I have attached my MySQL query below

```
create table table1 (
  DateandTime datetime,
  Name tinytext,
  Title varchar(255),
  Content Longtext unique(Title)
);
```

I know that this sounds too basic. But i dont have any solution.

I appreciate your feedbacks and Ideas. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried [`INSERT IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - ignore insert error: duplicate entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812437/mysql-ignore-insert-error-duplicate-entry)

Comment: Thank you Marcus Adams. Ignore works perfectly. I think single table is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Few solutions:

1. Unique column should prevent duplicate data
2. INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS
3. Use MERGE engine in MySQL (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/merge-storage-engine.html)

Answer (score 0):

I modified my query on Marcus Adams suggestion.

```
Insert Ignore table1 (
DateandTime,
Name,
Title,
Content)
values
(.......
);
```

I think single table is sufficient to address my issue.Thank you