# Setting to cause php error on duplicate entry attempt to unique fields?

Tags: php, mysql, unique-constraint, error-reporting, duplicates

In our PHP application, currently mysql query errors (syntax errors, duplicate entry errors for unique keys) are not throwing PHP errors, and script execution is continuing, which is fine.

I just want to know what setting (if it can be controlled by a setting) can stop script execution in the above mentioned cases, so that we are well aware and do not unknowingly do this by mistake.

I just read this question [MySQL - ignore insert error: duplicate entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812437/mysql-ignore-insert-error-duplicate-entry), which is about avoiding errors on duplicate entry attempts on unique fields. The answer by @zombat mentions using `insert ... ignore` to cause warnings instead of errors when there is a duplicate data entry attempt. So, it seems like a duplicate entry attempt (using `insert` and not `insert ... ignore`) causes a PHP error and script execution stops. Is this the default behavior?

I am not getting the PHP errors, at the first place. So, how do I get them?

Answer (score 1):

You should show some code.

But a few possibilities are:

You use error surpression with @ before the possible offending command.

You have custum errorhandlers that let the script continue.

You use exceptions instead of errors, and catch them.

Read here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php

We really need some code and some settings. You could scan your project for the string: set_error_handler