# how to check whether value exists or not in mysql database column while inserting

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv

i have a contactnumber column in mysql database. In contactnumber column there are more than 20,000 entries. Now when i upload new numbers through .csv file, i dont want duplicate numbers in database.
How can i avoid duplicate numbers while inserting in database.
I initially implemented logic that checks each number in .csv file with each of the number in database.
this works but takes lot of time to upload .csv file containing 1000 numbers.

Pleae suggest how to minimize time required to upload .csv file while not uploading duplicate values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add a `UNIQUE` constraint to the `contactnumber` column:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD UNIQUE (`contactnumber`);
```

From there you can use the `IGNORE` option to ignore the error you'd usually be shown when inserting a duplicate:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `mytable` VALUES ('0123456789');
```

Alternatively, you could use the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` to do something with the dupe, as detailed in this question: [MySQL - ignore insert error: duplicate entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812437/mysql-ignore-insert-error-duplicate-entry)

Comment: Your way is a lot better then mine

Answer (score 0):

If your `contactnumber` should not be repeated then make it `PRIMARY` or at least a `UNIQUE` key. That way when a value is being inserted as a duplicate, insert will fail automatically and you won't have to check beforehand.

Comment: i want to update my question... i also want to keem record of duplicate values. because there is telecaller column in database. so i want to keep track of duplicate values with associated telecaller name.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is to create a temporary table.

```
 create table my_dateasyyyymmddhhiiss as select * from mytable where 1=0;
```

Do your inserts into that table.

and then query out the orphans on the between mytable and the temp table based on contactnumber

then run an inner join query between the two tables and fetch out the duplicate for your telecaller  tracking.

finally drop the temporary table.

Thing that this does not address are duplicates within the supplied file (don't know if that would be an issue in this problem)

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to insert duplicate values in table and rather wants to keep that value in different table.

You can create trigger on table.
like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER unique_key BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  DECLARE c INT;
  SELECT COUNT(*) INTO c FROM table1 WHERE itemid = NEW.itemid;
  IF (c > 0) THEN
    insert into table2 (column_name) values (NEW.itemid);
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend this way

1. Alter the contactnumber column as UNIQUE KEY
2. Using phpmyadmin import the .csv file and check the option 'Do not abort on INSERT error' under Format-Specific Options before submitting

Comment: Thank you Rahul.. It helped alot