# alter table statment to insert duplicate into another table

Tags: mysql, database

I have a table in which there is a column name with `SP varchar(10) NOT NULL`. I want that column always to be unique so i created unique index on that column . My table schema as follows :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblspmaster` (
  `CSN` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SP` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `FileImportedDate` date NOT NULL,
  `AMZFileName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `CasperBatch` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `BatchProcessedDate` date NOT NULL,
  `ExpiryDate` date NOT NULL,
  `Region` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `FCCity` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `VendorID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LocationID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CSN`),
  UNIQUE KEY `SP` (`SP`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=10000000000 ;
```

Now i want that if anybody tries to insert duplicate record then that record should be inserted into a secondary table name `tblDuplicate`.

I have gone through this question [MySQL - ignore insert error: duplicate entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812437/mysql-ignore-insert-error-duplicate-entry) but i am not sure that instead of

```
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES (1,200) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value=200;
```

can i insert duplicate row into another table ?

what changes needed to be done in main table scheme or index column ?

**Note : Data will be inserted by importing excel or csv files and excel files generally contains 500k to 800 k records but there will be only one single column **

Comment: Can you use a stored procedure to do inserts/updates instead of direct SQL statements? If so the stored procedure can handle the logic of which table to insert into

Comment: Note : Data will be inserted by importing excel or csv files from a window service . any idea how can i implement that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use a trigger for this.  Here is the MySQL reference chapter on [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html).

Use a before insert trigger.  In the trigger, check if the row is a duplicate (maybe count(*) where key column value = value to be inserted).  If the row is a duplicate, perform an insert into your secondary table.

Comment: Excel file may be have around 500k records and in one day may be 20-30 files will be inserted . Is that trigger solution is feasable

Comment: trigger does not mean slow.  The trigger will run for each insert.  The slow portion will be the code that executes when the trigger executes, so try to make that efficient.

Comment: I use following command LOAD DATA local INFILE 'E://31october//Anuj taneja - SP//sp_files_sample1//400k sp00 6-19 E.csv'
INTO TABLE  tblspmaster
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
(sp); to insert csv file. now if i run the same file again then all entries should be go in to a secondary table .

Comment: the code to which I referred was the code in the trigger that you will be writting.