# PHP JSON Empty Data Remove - Newbie

Tags: php, json, post, filter

I am trying to remove the empty json data being posted. I tried the php function array_filter, but in all honesty, I am not sure if that is the right move.

```
 data[0][]  Test1
 data[0][]  91.00
 data[0][]  14.00
 data[1][]  Test2
 data[1][]  23.01
 data[1][]  14.00
 data[2][]  Test3
 data[2][]  32.00
 data[2][]  14.00
 data[3][0] 
 data[3][1] 
 data[3][2]
```

Comment: where is your php code?

Comment: The code (`?`) in your question doesn't make any sense.

Comment: $colMap = array(
    0 => 'Item',
    1 => 'Price',
    2 => 'Vat'
  );


  
  if (isset($_POST['changes']) && $_POST['changes']) {
    foreach ($_POST['changes'] as $change) {
      $rowId  = $change[0] + 1;
      $colId  = $change[1];
      $newVal = $change[3];
      
      if (!isset($colMap[$colId])) {
        echo "\n spadam";
        continue;
      }

   
      $select = $conn->prepare('SELECT SlipEntry_Idx FROM      slip_data     WHERE SlipEntry_Idx=? and Vendor_Slip_ID = 72 LIMIT 1');
      $select->execute(array(
        $rowId
      ));

Comment: I am trying to format the code LOL one moment

Comment: Add the code to the question.

Comment: If you need a bit of background, this example was for sqlite: http://warpech.github.io/jquery-handsontable/demo/php.html but i converted it to mysql pdo. What I am basically trying to achieve is preventing empty values from being saved causing: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '4' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 0):

Use json_decode to convert your json array to a php array and use array_filter to remove all empty keys.

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":,"d":4,"e":5}';
$json = json_decode($json);
$jsonFiltered = array_filter($json);
```

Maybe you need to do a array_map for a multidimensional array!

```
$json = array_map('array_filter', $json);
```

Didn't test this code!

Comment: I tried this: $colMap = json_decode($colMap);
$colMap = array_filter($colMap); once again apologies.. newbie. trying to learn this json thing

Comment: I think i will use this as a work around: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812437/mysql-ignore-insert-error-duplicate-entry I can not get the array filter to work

Comment: This did the trick, instead of trying to filter the json, I just make sure the empty data does not get writing to the database causing duplicate errors using INSERT IGNORE INTO