# MySQL - Replace Column Value

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to update/replace two column's value in a time.

```
UPDATE table_messages SET id_msg = 4, numbers_msg = 50;
```

and:

```
INSERT INTO table_messages (number_msg, id_msg) VALUES (50, 4);
```

mysql said: #1062 - Duplicate entry '4' for key 'PRIMARY'

both not working, what's the problem?
any other command?

Comment: It sounds like `id_msg` is your primary key.  That means that value has to be `distinct`.

Comment: you have a primary key on id_msg
so read this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812437/mysql-ignore-insert-error-duplicate-entry

Comment: are both reporting that message?  if so then there is already a id_msg=4 before the update.  If the update fails, it explains why the insert fails as there's already a 4 in the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your `id_msg` cant be duplicated because its `primary key` . you maybe interested to just update `numbers_msg`.

like that:

```
    UPDATE table_messages SET  numbers_msg = 50 WHERE id_msg = 4 ;
```

Or :

delete old id_msg = 4 and then use your query.

```
   INSERT INTO table_messages (number_msg, id_msg) VALUES (50, 4);
```