# How to insert only if there is no duplicate already?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want to insert a new user only, if there is no user with the same email already in the database.

I was reading this post: [MySQL - ignore insert error: duplicate entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812437/mysql-ignore-insert-error-duplicate-entry) but the problem there is that after the execution of the `sql` statement, i don't know if the new user was successful inserted or not.

Comment: If your column has `UNIQUE` index on it, you can use `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a regular insert, then check the error code afterwards:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT ... stuff that causes duplicate key error");
if (mysql_errno() == 1022) {
   ... account already exists ...
}
```

This is somewhat safer than doing a "select" first to see if the email exists, then inserting if it doesn't. Another parallel request might "steal" the account out from under you.

The mysql error codes are all documented here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-messages-server.html

---

comment followup:

My answer MAY be more reliable in some cases, e.g. consider this:

```
mysql> create table foo (x int primary key auto_increment, y  text);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into foo (y) values ('bar1'); // id #1
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into foo (y) values ('bar2'); // id #2
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into foo (x,y) values (2, 'bar2'); // try to create a dupe id #2
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '2' for key 'PRIMARY'
mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                2 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note how you STILL get a last_insert_id(). That's because it's always the value of the last **SUCCESSFUL** insertion. The value will not get reset just because an insert failed.

If you're doing multiple inserts with your DB handle, and try to use the `if last_insert_id == 0` trick, then you may get a false answer, because you'd be getting the ID of some OTHER insert that succeeded, not this one that just failed.

And note that `insert ignore` doesn't help either:

```
mysql> insert ignore into foo (x,y) values (1, 'bar1'); // create dupe id #1
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                2 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: no guarantees that oracle won't ever change them, but they'd have to be pretty stupid/desperate to actually do so. As for safer, see my edit above.

Comment: You're not using `INSERT IGNORE` in your example

Comment: @FuzzyTree: yeah, just added that.

Comment: turnaround on a last_insert_id() call is pretty minimal. that's just metadata kept inside the DB directly, and doesn't invole hitting the disk. but it would still be another query, v.s. checking something that's already present in the original insert's metadata response

Comment: When I do `INSERT IGNORE` on a dupe I get a 0 per documentation

Comment: well, I don't. v5.1.69 here. I'll take the actual live behavior of the DB any day over what the documentation claims. Though it should probably be filed as a bug report, if they really do want the `0` behavior to be what should happens.

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67535

Comment: Ah that explains it. I'm using a different version. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> after the execution of the sql statement, i don't know if it was
>   successful or not

If I understand correctly, you want to know whether an insertion occurred or not after using `INSERT IGNORE`. After executing your query call `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and if it returns 0 it means a row was not inserted.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

> If you use INSERT IGNORE and the row is ignored, the AUTO_INCREMENT
>   counter is not incremented and LAST_INSERT_ID() returns 0, which
>   reflects that no row was inserted.

**Test**

```
mysql> insert ignore into example (`id`, `data`) VALUES (2,'hello');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> insert ignore into example (`id`, `data`) VALUES (3,'hello');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)

mysql> insert ignore into example (`id`, `data`) VALUES (2,'hello');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select last_insert_id();
+------------------+
| last_insert_id() |
+------------------+
|                0 |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Warning**

Some versions of MySQL have a bug where `last_insert_id()` doesn't work correctly with `INSERT IGNORE`: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=67535

Comment: Excellent answer. REPLACE would bump the autoincrement id, and ON DUPLICATE KEY would probably return the current id that's stopping the insertion.

Comment: @tastro it would work, `LAST_INSERT_ID()` returns the data for the last query of the 'current' session (as opposed to the last global query)

Comment: I mean your answer as "> LAST_INSERT_ID() and if it returns 0 it means a row was not inserted" is not correct for some variants 
/please update your answer.. _others may misunderstand_

Comment: bonus, when is it too may not work: 

you have the InnoDB table and wish to use [AUTO_INCREMENT on a secondary column in a multiple-column index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-auto-increment.html)
so, we have a some stored-procedure with own AI increment for secondary field (i can show sample if you needed). That's all your variant not work again :) etc.

Answer (score 1):

if you use **PDO** it's simple:

```
try{
   // INSERT new account
}
catch(PDOException $ex){ /* already exist -> errorInfo */ }
```

it work if you have:

- **UQ** key for your email field
- [attr mode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) as `$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`

that's all

---

**added:**

*just in case for a proper understanding - [see comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580287/insert-only-if-there-is-no-duplicate-already-mysql-php-pdo#comment38092157_24580590)*:

Any DB-Layer, for example:

```
class TableExample
{
    ...    
    // sample with inner logic
    public function createUser(...)
    {
        ...
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO ...");
        ...
    }

    // sample with the AR etc.
    public function updateFooBar(...)
    {
        ...
        $user->name  = 'name';
        $user->email = 'email';
        $user->save();
        ...
    }    
}
```

Some X-layer:

```
class ModelStuff
{
    ....
    public function foo()
    {
        try{
            $this->example->createUser();
            ...
            $this->example->updateFooBar();
            ...
        }
        catch(PDOException $ex){
            // TODO: e.g. ($ex->getCode() == 23000)? ...
            // all PDOException with TableExample catched here
        }
    }
}
```

etc.

Compiled all my comment:

- [PDOException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) already aggregate the errorInfo (corresponds to [PDO::errorInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php))
  For accees you can simple use `$ex->getCode();` //[SQLSTATE - 23000](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html), which occurs for a duplicate-key error
- - Use the errorInfo for **more** detail about error e.g.: `$ex->errorInfo[1]` - where 1 is a [Driver specific error code](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.errorinfo.php)
- be careful with variant [LAST_INSERT_ID()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24580287/insert-only-if-there-is-no-duplicate-already-mysql-php-pdo#comment38085601_24580344)

Comment: @tastro [PDOException](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php) already aggregate the **errorInfo** (corresponds to [PDO::errorInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)) 
you can simple access as a `$e->errorInfo[1]` etc.  or what are you mean ? or what's the problem ? :)

Comment: @tastro it's example :) you can check with simple $e->[getCode()](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php); //[SQLSTATE - 23000](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/error-messages-server.html), which occurs for a duplicate-key error
**or** you may get [errorInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php) for **more** detail about error as [PDO::errorInfo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)... see your catched exception ~ var_dump($e); or in debugger |  

`But this way the code is longer` Compared with ? о_О

Comment: `..code is longer..` @tastro It's the OOP dialect and you should **already have** the try/cath block in the some level-layer for work with DB-Layer(~[Table-Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html), [AR](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html), or simple "direct access" I mean - "as is" :) In your question you wrote about **PDO** ? Right ?(title & tag) So, you needed only check the catch block in your x-layer. It works **if you did** as in my answer ^ 
I hope you(and all) understand - this block not for every request ? or i don't know what you mean :)

Comment: @tastro ok, no problem, I updated answer in order to avoid confusion..