# Verification of multiple rows in one condition before INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

I have table product:

```
 - id: int 
 - name: varchar(255)
 - articles_id  : int (foreign key)
 - number_document : varchar(255)
```

And I have table article:

```
 - id_article: int
 - name_article : varchar(255)
```

When inserting a product I chose one or more items through a select multiple option.
  But when I would insert an article or more in the same product I would check the various items that already exists, for example:

```
product1, name1, articles1, number_doc1
product1, name1, articles2, number_doc1
product1, name1, articles3, number_doc1
```

I would not insert these items in the same product

```
$num_doc= $_GET['doc'];
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM product WHERE document_number ='".$num_doc."'");

while ($var2 =  $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
    $a =   $var2['articles_id'];
    $b =   $var2['name']; 
    $c =   $var2['number_document']; 

    if (!empty($_POST['do'])) {
        $articles_id = $_POST["articles_id"];
        foreach ($articles_id as $art) {
            if ($a == $art) {
                echo 'already exist';
            } else {
                $sql = $db->query("INSERT INTO product(articles_id, name, document_number) values ('".$art."', '".$b."', '".$c."')");
            }
        }   
    }              
}

<form action ="POST">
    <div id="step-2">
        </br></br>
        <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" style="height: 300px">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Article <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <select class="select" style="width: 500px;position: absolute;margin-left: 500px" name="articles_id[]" multiple="multiple">
                <?php
                $sql='SELECT * FROM articles ';
                $list = $db->query($sql);
                while ($data = $list->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                    echo'<option value="'.$data['id_articles'].'">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$data['name_articles'] .'  '.$data['code_articles'].'</option>';
                }
                ?>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        </br></br></br></br>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-3">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="self.location.href='addInputs.php'">Non</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name ="do" value="update">Valider</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>But it inserted the same article that existed.  How do I prevent that?
```

Comment: Having some trouble following the question.  Would [INSERT / ON DUPLICATE KEY IGNORE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) help?  Are you familiar with that syntax

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - ignore insert error: duplicate entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812437/mysql-ignore-insert-error-duplicate-entry)

Comment: Frankly speaking, your code is terrible. You should spend some time learning how to prepare statements in MySQL, how to isolate raw sql statements from other code using ORM, how to separate raw PHP from HTML, using MVC pattern etc. It may take some time to learn all this.

Comment: If you alter your table and add a unique index on the columns you want to be unique, it will be impossible to create duplicate entries.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
$sql = $db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO product(articles_id, 
name, document_number) values ('".$art."', '".$b."', '".$c."')");
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are ignored. For example, without IGNORE, a row that
>   duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY value in the table
>   causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is aborted. With
>   IGNORE, the row is discarded and no error occurs. Ignored errors
>   generate warnings instead.

I would post more links to help you, but there are many.  Do a search on "php INSERT IGNORE INTO" or just search on your own `$sql = $db->query("INSERT IGNORE INTO` and you get lots of hits.