# PDO PHP bindParam() repeated use of same parameters

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, bindparam

Yesterday i decided to learn PDO and rewrite our server php to PDO.

The thing that jumped to my mind while rewriting the code is the need of repeated use of bindParam for the same parameters i already used.

Here is an example:

```
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $dbh->beginTransaction();
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Products(productID,numOfLikes) VALUES (:productID,0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE productID = productID;");
    $stmt->bindParam(":productID",$productID);
    $stmt->execute();

    if($customerID !== 0){  
        //*****Check, if customerID is in the Database, else add the customerID to the Database.
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO Customers(customerID) VALUES (:customerID) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE customerID = customerID;");
        $stmt->bindParam(":customerID",$customerID);
        $stmt->execute();

        //*****if customerID and productID are NOT registered together ,then register and add +1 to productID numOfLikes
        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT customerID, productID FROM CustomerProducts WHERE productID = :productID AND customerID = :customerID");          
        $stmt->bindParam(":productID",$productID);
        $stmt->bindParam(":customerID",$customerID);
        $stmt->execute();

        if ($stmt->rowCount() == 0) {
            //echo "added";
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO CustomerProducts(customerID, productID) Values (:customerID,:productID)");
            $stmt->bindParam(":customerID",$customerID);
            $stmt->bindParam(":productID",$productID);
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE Products SET numOfLikes = numOfLikes + 1 WHERE productID = :productID");
            $stmt->bindParam(":productID",$productID);
            $stmt->execute();  
        }else {
            //echo "removed";
            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM CustomerProducts WHERE productID = ".$productID." AND customerID = ".$customerID);
            $stmt->bindParam(":customerID",$customerID);
            $stmt->bindParam(":productID",$productID);
            $stmt->execute();

            $stmt = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE Products SET numOfLikes = numOfLikes - 1 WHERE productID = ".$productID);
            $stmt->bindParam(":productID",$productID);
            $stmt->execute();  
        }
    }
    $dbh->commit();
```

Is there a way to write it in "prettier way"?
Can you see any flows in that could. I would appreciate every help.

Note: this code will be for production use in the near future.

Comment: BTW, you forgot to use parameters in your DELETE statement. Same on the last UPDATE.

Comment: ow good one. thanks my friend !

Comment: Also you should use `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE customerID = VALUES(customerID)` if you want to set the new value instead of the existing value.

Comment: I didn't want to set new instead of existing. it is a trick i've seen from a guy on stackoverflow. it say insert, but ,if already existing do nothing in a fast way.

Comment: Why not just use `INSERT IGNORE` for that? Using `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` performs an insert then potentially an update.

Comment: @BillKarwin read the reason for that in the comments of the first answer suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/812437/mysql-ignore-insert-error-duplicate-entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is...

You can supply `bindParam` as an array to the `execute` function...

Something like this:

```
$statement->execute([
    ':username'=> $username,
    ':password'=> $password
]);
```

It's using `bindParam` and `execute` in just one statement, and it looks cleaner in my opinion.

Comment: It's more like using `bindValue()` because you can pass an expression instead of needing to pass an lvalue. Anyway yes, I always use an array argument to `execute()` too.

Comment: Yeah something like that.

Comment: but besides that i still need to use productID and customerID over and over in every query. can i store somewhere the binding and call it every time?

Comment: @ArielEstrin I don't think it's that necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get around the repeated variables by defining mySql user variables like this:

$psVars = $dbh->prepare("SET @pid = :productID;");

$psVars->bindParam(':productID', $productID);

$psVars->execute();

Then, in subsequent statements, just use @pid instead of a bound parameter